# Unable to run java servlet on Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, servlets, web.xml

I am trying to run a java servlet on an Ubuntu machine. I have copied my project directory and `web.xml` file below. I have Java and Tomcat9 installed, and Tomcat seems to be working properly, as the initial splash screen shows up on port `8080`. I have an `index.jsp` file in a `WebContent` folder which I can access and view just fine at `domain:8081/WebContent` (the project has been configured to run on port 8081), so it seems as though my `server.xml` file is correctly configured, however I am unable to run my servlets, `TrieDriver` and `SpellCheckDriver` and get a `HTTP Status 404 – Not Found`. In `servlet-class` tag in my `web.xml` file, I have tried prepending the package name to the servlet class name, as shown in the `AutoComplete` servlet definition, and without the package name, as shown in the `SpellCheck` servlet definition. I tried multiple combinations to try to access the page, `/SpellCheck/SpellCheck`, `/spellCheck/SpellCheck`, `/SpellCheck`, none of which worked, with combinations of `server-class` having the package and without. I tried looking at examples, and it seems as though my format follows what they have, but I can't get it to work. All help is appreciated.

Project Directory:

```
── SpellCheck
    ├── WEB-INF
    │   ├── classes
    │   │   ├── spellCheck
    │   │   │   ├── Main.class
    │   │   │   ├── SCNode.class
    │   │   │   ├── SiteFormat.class
    │   │   │   ├── SpellCheck.class
    │   │   │   └── SpellCheckDriver.class
    │   │   └── trie
    │   │       ├── Trie.class
    │   │       └── TrieDriver.class
    │   ├── src
    │   │   ├── spellCheck
    │   │   │   ├── Main.java
    │   │   │   ├── SCNode.java
    │   │   │   ├── SiteFormat.java
    │   │   │   ├── SpellCheck.java
    │   │   │   └── SpellCheckDriver.java
    │   │   └── trie
    │   │       ├── Trie.java
    │   │       └── TrieDriver.java
    │   ├── web.xml
    └── WebContent
        ├── META-INF
        │   └── MANIFEST.MF
        ├── index.jsp
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

        <servlet>
                <servlet-name>AutoComplete</servlet-name>
                <servlet-class>trie.TrieDriver</servlet-class>
        </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
                <servlet-name>AutoComplete</servlet-name>
                <url-pattern>/AutoComplete</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>



        <servlet>
                <servlet-name>SpellCheck</servlet-name>
                <servlet-class>SpellCheckDriver</servlet-class>
        </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
                <servlet-name>SpellCheck</servlet-name>
                <url-pattern>/SpellCheck</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: It is usually very helpful if you mention the error you are getting. What exactly happens when you try to access domain:8081/SpellCheck ?

Comment: @Kinnison84 I keep getting  `HTTP Status 404 – Not Found`. I have updated the question to include  that.